# Is there any library to combine multiple json schemas into single schema using java or springboot or nodejs

Tags: java, node.js, spring-boot

I have an input with array of Json schemas and I need to combine those multiple schemas into single schema, so is there any library in java or springboot to combine multiple schemas to single schemas

I found the link  which we can do using nodejs 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-merge-allof
but the steps are not clear so not able to understand to implement that

My input json schemas array as below

```
[
{
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
        "title": "PartyAddressArray",
        "description": "PartyAddressArray",
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "$ref": "PartyAddress"
        }
    },
    {
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
        "title": "PartyAddress",
        "description": "PartyAddress",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "description": "The unique identifier for a partyAddress",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "partyId": {
                "description": "The associated partyId for a partyAddress",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "addressType": {
                "description": "The address type for a partyAddress",
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                    "HOME",
                    "WORK",
                    "PERMANENT",
                    "COMMUNICATION",
                    "REGISTERED",
                    "SAIL",
                    "BUSINESS"
                ]
            },
            "languageCode": {
                "description": "The language code for a partyAddress",
                "type": "string",
                "maxLength": 10
            },
            "statusType": {
                "description": "The status type for a partyAddress",
                "type": "string",
                "enum": [
                    "PAST",
                    "CURRENT",
                    "FUTURE"
                ]
            },
            "effectiveDate": {
                "description": "The effective date for a partyAddress",
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date"
            },
            "endDate": {
                "description": "The end date for a partyAddress",
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date"
            },
            "postalAddress": {
                "description": "The postal address for a partyAddress",
                "$ref": "PostalAddress"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "addressType",
            "statusType"
        ],
        "example": {
            "id": "b9e2d964-e3ef-4c04-aaa9-31c46122e4g5",
            "partyId": "ff77a7a1-a637-40d2-b8f5-7da261f8bdc3",
            "addressType": "HOME",
            "languageCode": "EG",
            "statusType": "CURRENT",
            "effectiveDate": "13/03/2019",
            "endDate": "19/03/2019",
            "postalAddress": {
                "country": "India",
                "state": "MH",
                "city": "Mumbai",
                "zip": "40060",
                "line1": "Goregoan East1",
                "line2": "Goregoan East2",
                "line3": "Goregoan East3",
                "line4": "Goregoan East4",
                "line5": "Goregoan East5",
                "line6": "Goregoan East6",
                "line7": "Goregoan East7",
                "line8": "Goregoan East8",
                "line9": "Goregoan East9",
                "line10": "Goregoan East10",
                "line11": "Goregoan East11",
                "line12": "Goregoan East12"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

and I need to combine all the above json schemas into single schema

input is an array with json schemas and need to combine all schemas into single schema